# Replace whole HTML content of a DIV with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, html, replace, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Is it possible to replace whole HTML code of a DIV using Greasemonkey? This is the page:

```
<div id="mydiv">
  //plenty of code, probably 30 lines, with text, pictures and links
</div>
```

The ideal scenario would be to delete the content of "mydiv" on HTML level, and then add my edited code, probably as a string, but I am completely stuck. Is there a simple workaround for this?

Comment: `document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = "Hey! I'm replaced!"`

Comment: It works perfectly for string "Hey! I'm replaced!", but when I try to paste my chunk of HTML code, it has plenty of "Missing semocolon" errors and warnings and does not execute it at all.

Comment: You need to escape the HTML chunk so that it becomes a valid string literal. http://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html

Comment: Amazing! Works perfectly, thank you. :)